# Why is this not working? I cannot find any solution

Tags: vb.net

This program will ask the user for an input 4 times and then show 3 message boxes with 3 different answers. Each answers consists of 2 different numbers(range) but I can not run it because I cannot use the function.

My main problem is the function. The variables a, b, c, d will be provided by the user and x will be provided by me at the start of the program. I cannot run the program because Function is underlined with a blue line.

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim d As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim d As Integer


Function f(x As Double) As Double
    f = (a * x ^ 3) + (b * x ^ 2) + (c * x) + d
    Exit Function
End Function
Sub incremental()

    Dim left As Double
    Dim right As Double
    Dim product As Double
    Dim counter As Integer

    counter = 0
    left = -10
    right = -9.7
    product = 1

    a = InputBox("Please provide a coefficient for x^3.", "title", 0)
    b = InputBox("Please provide a coefficient for x^2.", "title", 0)
    c = InputBox("Please provide a coefficient for x^1.", "title", 0)
    d = InputBox("Please provide a coefficient for x^0.", "title", 0)

    Do While product > 0
        product = f(left) * f(right)

        If product > 0 Then
            left = right
            right = left + 0.3

        Else
            If counter = 0 Then
                MsgBox("Your approximate root is  " & left & "  and  " & right & ".")
                counter = counter + 1
                product = 1
                left = right
                right = left + 0.3

            ElseIf counter = 1 Then
                MsgBox("Your approximate root is  " & left & "  and  " & right & ".")
                counter = counter + 1
                product = 1
                left = right
                right = left + 0.3

            Else : counter = 2
                MsgBox("Your approximate root is  " & left & "  and  " & right & ".")
                counter = 3

            End If

        End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is not that well written, or organized. What exactly is your question?

Comment: You have a typo—`roght`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see our articles on [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [On-Topic Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The time invested in these short documents will be worth it as you will likely get better answers more quickly by following their advice. Pay special attention to your title - this one couldn't be more vague.

Comment: `Option Strict` will prevent this and many other bugs

Comment: You just edited the question and forgot to finish what you were explaining!! "my main problem is the function a, b, c, d will be provided by the user and x will be" what will "x" be??

Comment: You can't write a function/sub inside a function/sub. The error message should help you understand what is hapenning. You should write your code a little bit at a time and see if it compiles.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is just another one of your typos or if this is actually the problem, but you are missing the "End Sub" part:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim b As Integer
    Dim c As Integer
    Dim d As Integer

' --------------------
End Sub  ' <----------
' --------------------


Function f(x As Double) As Double
```

That's why `Function` is underlined in blue.

But that will not fix your code. It's still broken because you don't understand the fundamentals of object-oriented programming. There's not much I can offer you in that regard... it's just too big of a subject.

For example, you've declared `Button1_Click` to handle your button clicks. You say that `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` will be provided by the user, but that never seems to happen (you aren't assigning anything to them). You then end the function, causing the `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` variables to be deleted (or rather, the memory addresses held by those variables to be released).

Meanwhile, your function `f` references variables named `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` but never declares them. Looks like you are trying to use the variables from your `Button1_Click` function, but `Button1_Click` and `f` are completely different contexts - they cannot access one another's variables. If you want to pass `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` to `f`, you must pass those values as parameters (`f(x, a, b, c, d)`) or get them by some other means (such as declaring them as object-level properties, etc.).

It looks like this might be a programming homework assignment, so I'm not going to say anything more than that except "good luck".

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew Arnold stated:

```
roght = left + 0.3
```

should be changed to this:

```
right = left + 0.3
```

Comment: +1 for spotting that, even though it (apparently) was not the OP's only issue.